# The choice... Core Animation vs cocos2d

Tags: iphone, core-animation

After improving my self thanks to you, i want to do something mire serious.

Thé problem is that i'm still a beginner, making app is quite easy on iOS i admit.

So there is my problem : want i wanna do is a planet, on screen you Will only see a part or the planet and the user moving his finger from left to right or from right to left will make the planet move and discover more of the planet. 
so basicly i wanna do a carroussel you only see a part of, like in the app GF All Stars (you'll find it on the app store), i also want make little animation like people walking on it or birds... so there is my question : what is the best way to do something like that ??? should i use Core animation provide by Apple or it is too much and i must turn to games library like coco2SD ??? i have no idea which one is easier.

if you have any informations thanks for all, and if you ever seen a caroussel tutorial thanks !

Comment: Please edit your post for English grammar, capitalization, and punctuation. See [English.SX](http://english.stackexchange.com/) if you have any questions about English usage.

Answer (score 0):

Given the limited functionality of the game you are trying to make Coocos2D should be more than fine and will probably be easier to wrap your head around. The arguments against using Cocos2D are that CoreAnimation is something that you should probably learn if you really want to get into iOS game development. And, (this is more my pet peeve) it seems like your app will be relatively small and that there is a good chance that Cocos2D will add a lot of extra code that you do need to your App; admittedly this isn't really a big deal, but I always like to keep a lean ratio of external to internal code in my iOS apps.

Ultimately, if you want to be able to really hit the ground running and quickly jump into the code, then Cocos2D is probably the way to go, as it is easier to pick up than CoreAnimation.